# Is SAS relevant software to modern machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, sas

I have an opportunity to attend SAS course and get certification, while getting my formal education. Is SAS relevant software for modern machine learning?

I'm a former software engineer, so I'm fluent in Python/R, Scikit-learn, Theano/Lasagne, whilst have no real experience, but sure will be able to run Hadoop/Spark/Mesos distributed stack, if needed.

I also know that many big tech companies have in-house machine learning pipelines, which allow to build predictive models visually, then compile them to Java or C++ binary and push it to production.

Does SAS more relate to statistical modelling side of things? Is it desktop software for rapid prototyping of predictive models? Is knowing SAS and its' built-in language beneficial in modern world of XGBoost and neural networks?

Comment: This isn't a good fit for the site, IMHO. It strikes me as *primarily opinion-based* (ie, off topic), although we've sometimes let such questions slide by as CW before. FWIW, SAS does have a data mining application (that you have to purchase separately), but I think it's more oriented to business people without a background in statistics or machine learning. Certainly anyone who is working w/ low-level C++ implementations or Hadoop, or anything like that, isn't going to be using SAS's data mining software.